# How to whitelist IPv6 in AWS Security Group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My public IP is in IPv6 format.
I want to whitelist it in the security group inbound rule.I added it as usual like this :
[image: Screenshot]

But it doesn't work for some reason. I tried converting it to IPv4 and added that but still cannot access. What am I doing wrong please help.

Comment: How did you test it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your VPC setup to use IPv6 and does the subnet your instance resides in have an IPv6 range attached to it?

You will also need to ensure your VPC has a route in the route table of your instance to allow `::/0` outbound for the internet (over an internet gateway as your instance is public).

Assuming all of these exist use [DIG](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/) against the hostname you are connecting to, to validate it has an `AAAA` record to allow the domain to resolve for IPv6 addresses.

Here is some more information about [setting up IPv6 for your VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/get-started-ipv6.html).

Answer (score -1):

For IPV6 to be whitelisted and accessed anywhere for specific port just enter ::/0 in the source field.

### for exmple:

for opening Porte 80

port: 80   Source:**0.0.0.0/0** (for ipv4)

port: 80   Source: **::/0** (for ipv6)

Comment: Do not do this! The OP has a specific IP address they want to permit. This answer may allow the traffic to flow, but from everyone in the world! A sure way to get hacked.